# Website breaks after adding external font to default_head_blocks.xml

Tags: magento2, frontend, fonts, font-family

I created a custom theme that inherits from another theme that in turn inherits from Magento Luma theme.

I added the the file `default_head_blocks.xml` to my theme:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <link src="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light" src_type="url" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <css src="owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css" />
        <css src="fancybox/css/jquery.fancybox.css" />
        <css src="icon-fonts/css/porto-icons-codes.css" />
        <css src="icon-fonts/css/animation.css" />
        <script src="jquery.js" />
        <script src="fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

After that everthing was still working. But when I add the follwoing line to the file then the site breaks which means empty page in Firefox. Chrome says 500.

```
<link src="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2" src_type="url" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

After adding the line to the file. I execute

```
magento cache:clean
magento setup:di:compile
```

There are neither errors in the browser console nor in the server logs.

Why is the site breaking when I add this line?

Comment: tried `rm -rf var/view_view_preprocessed/*` and `rm -rf pub/static/*` then redeploy the statics `magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Try this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run below commands :

magento setup:static-content:deploy

magento setup:upgrade

magento c:c

magento c:f